# Enforce artifact only depends on artifacts of equal or lower Java source version

Tags: java, maven, java-8, migration, java-7

I'm in the process of upgrading a huge system with 3000+ java maven projects and repos deployed as a monolith war from Java 7 to 8. We will try to migrate parts of the system at a time, meaning some artifact will be built with jdk7 and some jdk8.

The question is; Is there a way (maven plugin or something) to enforce (fail the build) when artifacts built with jdk7 depend on jdk8 artifacts. The reverse (jdk8 -> jdk7) is allowed and also jdk8 -> jdk8. I don't think any of the built in rules in the maven enforcer plugin does this, and it might be difficult and time consuming to do?

Hope I'm being clear. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the original answer is gone, let me write it again with more details.

You can use the extra enforcer rule

http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/enforceBytecodeVersion.html

You configure this plugin to use at most JDK 1.7 (with the `maxJdkVersion` property) in all your projects. Then you disable the check for all projects you have already migrated to Java 8.

Comment: Thanks, This should work, though it would be nice to have something that detects the dependecy error automatically since there are thousands of projects in play.

Comment: You probably set `maven.compiler.source` to specify your compile version, right? Then you can use `${maven.compiler.source}` in the definition of the rule. Then you do not have change anything.